# Display Special Character in Repeater Based on the DataItem Value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, arraylist, data-binding, repeater

I'm calling a stored procedure by passing the input from the webpage and saving the results in ArrayList. Each record in the ArrayList has column with name: type. If type is "A", 
then I need display a special character on web page for the column value for the associated row.For the remaining type records in the results ArrayList, 
i don't need to display anything for the associated rows..

in code behind file:

```
Dim array As New ArrayList

            array = outPutFromTheSporedProcedure
              repeater1.DataSource = array
            repeater1.DataBind()
```

On aspx.page:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" runat="server">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th> type  </th>
                                            </tr>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <tr>
                                       <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl123" runat="server"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "type")%></asp:Label></td>
                                </tr>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                </table></td></tr>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
```

On Aspx Page
I have a repeater and binding a data item to repeater in itemTemplate.
Now i need to display special character(i.e *, $, &, basically to differentiate from other type of rows) 
for type of rows "A", for remaining rows, i need to display nothing for the records for the associated column.

Please let me know how to solve this one. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: This looks more like VB than C#

Comment: What Type is outPutFromTheSporedProcedure?

Comment: it is type of arraylist @NoAlias

Comment: And the ArrayList consists of objects of what type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to display nothing for the non-special conditions you must first change this:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl123" runat="server"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "type")%></asp:Label></td>
```

To This:

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl123" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
```

Now, set your special character in the Repeater_ItemDataBound Event Handler if the conditions are met:

```
Private Sub repeater1_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles repeater1.ItemDataBound

    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then

        If CType(e.Item.DataItem, UnderlyingTypeOfArrayList).type = "A" Then

            CType(e.Item.FindControl("lbl123"), Label).Text = "*" 'Special Character

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

You see above that I check for the correct RepeaterItemType, if tghe DataItem's type Property = A, and if so, I get an instance of the label using FindControl and Casting to set its Text to the special character.

Note: You'll have to change UnderlyingTypeOfArrayList to the Type contained in the ArrayList.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This Question is extension to this Question: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32743516/vb-net-how-to-call-another-stored-procedures-based-on-stored-procedure-result-a/32750304#32750304). The repeater i mentioned is the rptSP2 in the old question, for that rptSP2 display  i need display this special character. The error i'm getting here is **Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types**  .. it may be because i couldn't able access repeater 2 in its ItemDataBound Event..  Any suggestions please?

Comment: In rptSP1_ItemDataBound: AddHandler rptSP2.ItemDataBound, AddressOf repeater1_ItemDataBound.  You may want to change the name of repeater1_ItemDataBound to rptSP2_ItemDataBound (and then update the AddressOf statement accordingly).

Comment: Sorry to say this it is not still working... any help please
`Private Sub rptSP1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptSP1.ItemDataBound
 If  
//some code
 Dim rptSP2 As Repeater = CType(e.Item.FindControl("rptSP2"), Repeater)
AddHandler rptSP2.ItemDataBound, AddressOf rptSP2_ItemDataBound
 rptSP2.DataSource = D4
  rptSP2.DataBind()
end if
    End Sub`
AND 
`Private Sub rptSP2_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptSP2.ItemDataBound
    End Sub`

Comment: You can remove the "Handles rptSP2.ItemDataBound"